# Double and triple integrals to find volume below surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I want to find the volume in the first octant lying under the paraboloid $z=1-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{81}$

I used the substitution $x=2r\cos\theta$ and $y=9r\sin\theta$ to obtain
$$\iint (1-r^2)r drd\theta = \iint r-r^3 drd\theta$$.

But what are my bounds here? I assumed $0 \rightarrow 2\pi$ for the integral with respect to theta, but since we're in the first octant I'm thinking $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead. Im not sure about the integral with respect to $r$ though, I thought from 0 to 2 first, but that doesn't seem to give me the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there are some confusions in a different answer/comments. First a little bit about the geometry: the paraboloid goes in $z$ from $0$ to $1$, At every $z$ in this range, the projection one the $xy$ plane is an ellipse, with ratio of the axes $2:9$. At $z=0$ and $x=0$ we get maximum $y=9$, and $z=y=0$ implies maximum $x=2$.

Now we want to calculate the volume. We start with a volume element $\Delta z(x,y)dx dy$, where $\Delta z$ is the height from the $xy$ plane to the paraboloid. In this case $\Delta z(x,y)=z(x,y)=1-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{81}$. The limits of integration are such as the $(x,y)$ point is in the quarter of the ellipse $1-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{81}=0$, which we can write $x$ from $0$ to $2$ and $y$ from $0$ to $9\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}$.

We can also write the same integral in a "cylindrical" or "polar" coordinate system. We do the transformation in the question $x=2r\cos\theta$ and $y=9r\sin\theta$. When I plug these in,the volume is going to be $$V=\iint 18(1-r^2) r drd\theta$$
The factor of $18$ appears from the Jacobian $J=18r$. The limits are $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi/2$ and $r=0$ to $r=1$

Comment: Thank you, this lead to the correct answer! I forgot about the jacobian aswell.

Comment: No problem. I see that many comments/answers suggest that this is a common issue

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of OP's transformation
\begin{cases}
x &= 2r \cos \theta \\
y &= 9r \sin \theta \\
\rlap{x,y \ge 0}
\end{cases}
is
\begin{cases}
r &= \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{y^2}{81}} \\
\theta &=
\left\{
\begin{align}
\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right) &\quad \text{if } x > 0 \\
\frac\pi2 &\quad \text{if } x = 0
\end{align}
\right.
\end{cases}
Since the solid lies in the first octant, we have $x,y,z \ge 0$.  The paraboloid can be written as $z = 1 - r^2$.  This suggests $0 \le r \le 1$ since $r$ is nonnegative.

The range of $\theta$ in the question ($[0,\frac\pi2]$) is correct.

The Jacobian is

$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}\right| = 18r$$

This gives the required volume

\begin{align}
\iint_{\text{paraboloid}} (1-r^2)r drd\theta
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} 18 \left(\int_0^1 (r-r^3) dr \right) d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} 18 \left( \frac12 - \frac14 \right) d\theta \\
&= 18 \cdot \frac14 \cdot \frac\pi2 \\
&= \frac{9\pi}{4}
\end{align}